# Is there a better way to override all instances of a templated systemd unit?

Tags: systemd

I ran into an issue with vncserver needing to wait for my autofs-managed home directory. I have multiple users that will need VNC access. The vnc server is started by systemd.

I'm aware that I could do:

```
systemd edit vncserver@:1.service
systemd edit vncserver@:2.service
systemd edit vncserver@:3.service
```

etc and add:

```
[Unit]
After=autofs.service
```

to each, but I'd rather not be repeating myself when they all need the same edit.

I'm also aware that I could copy the unit file to /etc/systemd/system and just add my line there and then enable instances of that template.

My question is, does systemd have an in-built way to edit all instances of a templated unit at once, or do I need to go with one of the solutions above, or is there some other way to do this I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

`systemd edit vncserver@.service` seems to work.
It may be that this was not the case when you asked the question though.